# How to create a vector every iteration of a for loop?

Tags: r, nested-for-loop

I have a vector containing different names e.g. `(apple, apple, apple, pear, grape, apple)`

For each of these names, I would like to create a vector, whose elements are a binary 1/0 depending on whether that name appears in the corresponding entry.

So I want my nested for-loop to return, from my example, three vectors:

- `apple <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)`
- `pear  <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`
- `grape <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)`

Here is the code I've tried:

```
for(i in SurgList) { 
  for(j in Surgeons) {
    assign("i", "i")
    ifelse(i==j, append(i, 1), append(i,0))
  }  
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is `SurgList` and `Surgeons`?  Do you need a `for` loop? i.e.  If you have a `vector` i.e. `v1 <- c("apple", "apple", "apple", "pear", "grape", "apple")` do `table(seq_along(v1), v1)` create the matrix of biinary. Or use `model.matrix(~ 0 +  v1)`

Comment: Greetings! It looks like `SurgList` is some form of data or object. Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: I'm working with a large data set that has the information for different surgeons and the surgeries they performed. in my example, the surgeons are replaced with fruit. You can think of 'Surgeons' as 'c(apple, apple, apple, pear, grape, apple)' and 'SurgList' as 'unique(Surgeons)'

Comment: @MaxNurko In that case, you don't need a nested loop as it would be less efficient compared to a table or `model.matrix`

Comment: @akrun I am not familiar with model.matrix, I will do some syntax research and might be back with another question, thank you!

Comment: The `syntax` provided in the code should work for your vector

Comment: @akrun I'm not sure I understand the code though...  would `model.matrix(~ 0 +  v1)` give a matrix that is 3x6 so that each column represents a different fruit and the entries under that column delineate whether that fruit occurs in that entry number for v1?

Comment: Yes, it does create column for each unique entry and the dummy columns with 1 represent the position where that value is present in the original vector

Comment: With a nested loop, it would be `O(n^2)` (as you mentioned big dataset)

Answer (score 0):

```
v0 <- c('apple', 'pear', 'grape')  # Targets to be checked
v1 <- c('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'grape', 'apple')  # Input vector

list_01 <- list()                  # Create an empty list to store each vectors
for (i in v0){                     # v0 = Targets to be checked
    list_ <- list(i = +(v1 == i))  # Compare if the input vector meet the case
    names(list_) <- i
    list_01 <- append(list_01, list_)  # Store the vector into list
}

list_01  # The binaries are stored in this list

apple <- list_01$apple  # Each groups' binaries could be 
pear <- list_01$pear    # extracted as a vector
grape <- list_01$grape
```

### Console Output:

```
> list_01
$apple
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 1

$pear
[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0

$grape
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0

> apple
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 1
> pear
[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0
> grape
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0
```